# How to Store and Update then again store in useState

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using here useState to store data, update current value, by using this it's not store previous data, it's only store update current value which do useState. But I want to store previous data and update data all of them, somethings like, i have 10 api's data and i want to call them end of my api using ids.

i want to store 10 api's data in one array.

how to store 10 apis data in together using useState();

my code is somethings like:

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]); 
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
useEffect(() => {
        ids?.map((id) => {
            fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc(dataLoc.title))
                .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        })
    }, []);

    console.log(dataLoc);
```

output is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f55zy.png)

but it's in 10 array the out put but i want all the title in one array.

anyone can help me how can i do this here?
ThankYou for Your Trying in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of react states `prev`-callback like that:

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  ids?.map((id) => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc((prev) => [...prev, dataLoc.title]))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });
}, []);

console.log(dataLoc);
```

By spreading `...prev` and appending it with `, dataLoc.title` you add each entry to the previous state value. The order is the one in which the calls go through, since we insert the new element at the end.

#### Edit

If you want to console.log multiple times you can make use of another `useEffect` inside your component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(dataLoc);
}, [dataLoc]);
```

Comment: it's working fine but when i use it in my project, the first reload it's givimg me empty array, is there any way to repeat console.log 2, 3 time?

Comment: You want to console.log multiple times?

Comment: yes, Sir. exactly !

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly, how about now?

Comment: inside the component means, i'm a bit confused sir, if you show me?

Comment: can write in comment, i will get.

Comment: It is meant that you can put that `useEffect` snippet on the same level where you have your `dataLoc` state

Comment: look, when i am trying to fetch multiple API using map() method, and launch the project it's given me empty which is i understand my console.log couldn't able to fetch at the time, and just use Ctrl+s press to save the file again, it's start to giving me value in react native vs code. in this case how can i avoid to launch the project and again Ctrl+s press. what should i use to avoid them and once i launch, i will able to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The code is enqueueing state updates in a loop and not updating from the previous state. In other words, each enqueued update in the loop overwrites the previous update. The update from the last loop iteration is the one the app sees on the subsequent render.

## Solution

Either use a functional state update to correctly enqueue state updates and update from the previous state. Use `.forEach` instead of `.map`.

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  ids?.forEach((id) => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc(dataLoc => [...dataLoc, dataLoc.title]))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  })
}, []);
```

Or map the `ids` to an array of Promises and `Promise.all` them and enqueue a single state update.

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const requests = ids?.map((id) => {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataLoc) => return dataLoc.title)
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  });

  Promise.all(requests)
    .then(ids => {
      setDataLoc(ids)
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is overriding the previous values. You can merge the values

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    ids?.map((id) => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((dataLoc) =>
          setDataLoc((prevState) => {
            return [...prevState, dataLoc.title];
          })
        )
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: it's working!  is there any way to fetch 2/3 times every 5 sec?

Answer (score 0):

you can use *push* method to add each title to the Array:

```
    const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]); 
    const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    useEffect(() => {
    ids?.map((id) => {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc(dataLoc.push(dataLoc.title)))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    })
}, []);

console.log(dataLoc);
```

Comment: `setDataLoc(dataLoc.push(dataLoc.title))` will update the state to the result of the `.push` method, which is the new length of the array, not the updated array.